# Mongo casbah: cannot resolve "++"

Tags: mongodb, scala, import, driver, casbah

Casbah version: 2.8.0

Following example here: http://api.mongodb.com/scala/casbah/2.0/tutorial.html#combining-multiple-dbobjects

I'm using below as import statements.

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.AggregationOutput
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.TypeImports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.{MongoDBList, MongoDBObject}
```

And below `++` got `Cannot resolve symbol ++` error.

```
val basic = MongoDBObject(
  "id" -> "123",
  "project" -> "pp123"
)

val createdTime = MongoDBObject(
  "createdTime" -> MongoDBObject(
    "$exists" -> false
  )
)

val query = basic ++ createdTime
```

I tried to Google but didn't find much, the [official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/2.8/getting-started/) didn't help either...

I guess I'm just missing an import statement for `++`, but I don't know which one to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick grep of the source reveals two `++` methods on the `MongoDBObject` class:

```
> grep -r "def ++" .
./casbah-commons/src/main/scala/MongoDBObject.scala:  def ++(pairs: (String, Any)*): DBObject = {
./casbah-commons/src/main/scala/MongoDBObject.scala:  def ++[A <% DBObject](other: A): DBObject = {
```

The second one looks relevant here. `<%` denotes a view bound, so you need an implicit conversion from `MongoDBObject` to `DBObject`.

```
> grep -r "implicit .*: DBObject =" .
./casbah-commons/src/main/scala/Implicits.scala:  implicit def map2MongoDBObject(map: scala.collection.Map[String, Any]): DBObject =
./casbah-commons/src/main/scala/Implicits.scala:  implicit def unwrapDBObj(in: MongoDBObject): DBObject = in.underlying
```

It looks like you can import `com.mongodb.casbah.Implicits._` to get this.